# Reinstall of Visual Studio 2010 Professional does not install C++ headers and libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have a Windows7 x64 machine (german). I had VS2008Prof, VS2010Prof and VS11 DP installed. I work mainly with VS2010. I was experimenting with the latest Qt version and tried to get html5 video running with QtWebKit. I installed some codecs and then also the Windows SDK 7.1.

Suddenly the VS2010 debugger began to behave strange: it showed local (stack) variables correctly, but heap variables (including the this pointer) showed wrong values when stepping through some method. And I am sure that this was not the fault of my code.

I then tried to revert my changes and ended up uninstalling the Win SDK 7.1, the VS11 DP and VS2010, the latter several times with the standard uninstall and with VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe. After each uninstall I tried to reinstall VS2010: It reported a successfull install (including C++) but in the Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include folder there are only the three files ammintrin.h, srv.h and wmiatlprov.h. The lib folder only contains the amd64 and ia64 folders and no C++ or msvc100* libraries.

Any ideas or suggestions?

(I also posted this on social.msdn.microsoft.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by re-installing the complete system. Perhaps VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe /full /netfx may have helped, but I overlooked the /full switch.

Comment: Have the same problem, tried the uninstaller several times without success.